# How can I buffer a polygon using SimplePolygon2D correctly?

Tags: java, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I use the following Java to draw polygons on a google map:

```
public List<LatLng> create(List<LatLng> footprint)
{
    SimplePolygon2D polygon = createPolygon(footprint);
    if (polygon.isBounded())
    {
        polygon = createPolygon(Lists.reverse(footprint));
    }

    Collection<Point2D> bufferPoints = polygon.buffer(-.00003).boundary().vertices();

    List<LatLng> footprintOfBuffer = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    for (Point2D point2D : bufferPoints)
    {
        footprintOfBuffer.add(new LatLng(point2D.x(), point2D.y()));
    }

    return footprintOfBuffer;
}

private SimplePolygon2D createPolygon(List<LatLng> footprint)
{
    SimplePolygon2D polygon = new SimplePolygon2D();
    for (LatLng latLng : footprint)
    {
        polygon.addVertex(new Point2D(latLng.getLat(), latLng.getLng()));
    }
    return polygon;
}
```

This produces good results for squares but not for other polygons. See results below:

[image]

1, 2, 3, 5, and 6 are good enough for my use case, but I am not sure why4 and 7 seem to have and extra vertex that throws the buffer off.

I had some issues with that originally before I started checking the isBounded() method and reversed the order of vertices if needed. Another interesting thing I noticed is that the extra vertices get added in between the first and last vertices that I create.

I am probably missing something simple, but I can't seem to figure out why this happens.

Does anyone have any thoughts or direction on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is just a bug in the JavaGeom library. I just tried using the JTS library to do the same thing and the results are MUCH better. I have tried breaking it with crazy polygons but it has worked on all of them (very impressive). See results below:

[image]

UPDATE: The JTS library rocks! I have used it for a lot of things since I wrote this.